# Possible to link .xib to class written within a class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I like to keep my code clean and I have multiple classes written for custom cells right now. Most of those cells are used in only 1 `UITableView`.

So lets say we have the classes `CustomUITableViewController` and `CustomUITableViewCell`. What I'm looking for is something along these lines in the `CustomUITableViewController`.

```
@interface CustomUITableViewController()
//stuff
@end

@interface CustomUITableViewCell : UITableViewCell
//stuff
@end

@implementation CustomUITableViewCell
//stuff
@end

@implemention CustomUITableViewController
    -(UITableViewCell*)cellForRowAtIndexPath... {
        CustomUITableViewCell *cell = dequeueCellFor...
        return cell;
    }
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad]

        //this next line should be right?????
        [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }
@end
```

1. Is my `viewDidLoad` method correct? I should write it just like I would if I was writing the `UITableViewCell` in a separate file?
2. What do I put in the .xib file? When I try to change the class to a custom class it doesn't link up with `CustomUITableViewCell`, and of course it doesn't match up with `CustomUITableViewController` (although I tried anyways.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. What do you mean by 'doesn't link up with `CustomUITableViewCell`'? As long as your `nib` object is the nib for your custom cell, and in the xib for that cell the root object is a UITableViewCell with its custom class property set to your CustomUITableViewCell type you should be good to go. I've used this approach myself, although I've found that putting logic in the cells is more pain than it's worth.

On a side note, you should [be sure to use a three letter prefix with all your classes to avoid collisions with Apple private classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html).

The "Not KVC compliant" error is usually caused by one of two things in this situation:

1) You modified the XIBs but Xcode didn't notice the change and so didn't deploy the modified file. This usually occurs when you change something like the cell identifier in the XIB. Delete your app from the simulator/device and try running again.

2) You had properties declared on the custom class for the cell (or possibly something else unrelated in the view hierarchy) that were connected in IB at one time, but you've since changed the class behind IB's back and it doesn't know that it shouldn't try to make those connections again. Right-click each view in the scene to look for any broken connections and remove them. This happens to me if I correct the spelling of a property or change it in any way and don't remove and re-add the connection in IB. 95% of the time, this is the problem when I see that error.

Comment: It doesn't link because I'm writing the CustomUITableViewCell class in the file for the class CustomUITableViewController. I do not have a separate file for it. It says that it is not KVC compliant when I build and run it. But you have typed classes inside other class files and linked the xib to it like what I am trying to do? Or was it a miscommunication? Zed is mentioning that it isn't possible, which I'm unfortunately beginning to believe.

Comment: I'm 100% certain that the Interface Builder class parser doesn't care where you declare & implement a class. This is why you can declare properties in private extensions (categories without a name) and IB still picks it up. To test, I just declared the interface and implementation for a cell in the .m for a controller, and IB allowed me to set the custom class for the cell to that type. It builds and runs just fine. Make sure you have the cell identifier set in the xib for the custom cell to the same string you use to register and dequeue the cell.